# Adding UISegmentedControl to UIScrollView programmatically

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am tyring to add UISegmentedControl to UIScrolview programmatically.
I am using below code..

I don't why the scrollview is not enabled.

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 435)];
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 700);
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;

    NSArray *menu = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Accountimg.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Challengesimg.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Profileimg.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Challengesimg.png"],nil];
    UISegmentedControl *menuSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:menu];
    menuSegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,450,40);
    menuSegmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

    [scroll addSubview:menuSegmentedControl];
     [menuScrollView addSubview:scroll];
    [menuSegmentedControl release];
    [scroll release];
```

I am unable to scroll horizontally..

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

I am able to get the horizontal scroll.

Code updated:

```
 menuSegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,500,35);
    menuSegmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

     menuScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(menuSegmentedControl.frame.size.width, menuSegmentedControl.frame.size.height);
    menuScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

    [menuScrollView addSubview:menuSegmentedControl];
    menuScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Thank you.

Comment: You add the segmented controller as a subview of a scrollview and then add that scrollview as a subview of another scrollview? you shouldn't have a scrollview on top of another

Comment: Hi @AndreiFilip, the second one is not a scrollview. I added segmented control to scrollview and then it to UIview. Here menuscrollview is a UIView(Sorry for confusion). Thanks for reply.